# Installing pyosmium

Tags: macos, boost, openstreetmap, canopy, osmium

I've been having trouble installing [pyosmium](http://osmcode.org) on OS X 10.8 with the Canopy installation of Python. I'm not sure where the headers should go, and I get different install errors depending on where I try.

I've installed the dependencies (Boost.Python, osmium, etc.). I think the problem is related to the location of the Canopy Python installation compared to these dependencies. See [this](https://github.com/GalSim-developers/GalSim/wiki/Installation-FAQ#in-mac-osx-what-can-i-do-if-im-having-trouble-getting-boostpython-to-work-with-enthought-canopy-python) thread on similar challenges installing Boost with Canopy.

I've tried installing Boost (and Boost Python) and osmium into:
/usr/local/include

I then run 
`python setup.py build`
to install pyosmium, and get the error:
lib/osmium.cc:3:10: fatal error: 'osmium/visitor.hpp' file not found

Adding a symbolic link to the osmium directory to /Library/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/include/, I get the error:
/usr/local/include/osmium/visitor.hpp:36:10: fatal error: 'type_traits' file not found

If I install them in /Users/[username]/Library/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/include/, I get:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "setup.py", line 31, in 
    raise Exception("Cannot find boost_python library")

Other permutations raise similar errors. Ideas would be much appreciated!

UPDATE: after more trying, the problem seems to be that `setup.py` for pyosmium cannot find the boost headers. I added the path to boost to the `includes` list in `setup.py`. However, it still can't find type_traits and the other boost headers.

```
> $ python setup.py build
> running build 
> running build_py 
> running build_ext
> building 'osmium._osmium' extension
> gcc -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -dynamic -arch x86_64 -DNDEBUG -g -O3 -arch x86_64 -I/usr/local/include/boost_1_57_0 -I/usr/include -I../libosmium/include -I../boost -I/Applications/Canopy.app/appdata/canopy-1.5.0.2717.macosx-x86_64/Canopy.app/Contents/include/python2.7 -c lib/osmium.cc -o build/temp.macosx-10.6-x86_64-2.7/lib/osmium.o -std=c++11 -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64
> In file included from lib/osmium.cc:3:
> /usr/local/include/osmium/visitor.hpp:36:10: fatal error: 'type_traits' file not found
> #include <type_traits>
     ^
> 1 error generated.
> error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

Comment: `type_traits` is a C++ header. Do you have g++ installed?

Comment: Thanks, scai. I'm not sure. I installed the Xcode developer tools, which allowed me to do the builds. Is there a way that I can check for g++ or install it? Having said that, I can see type_traits.hpp in my usr/local/include/boost_1_57_0/boost directory

Comment: No idea how you can check that on OS X. On Linux there will be a file similar to `/usr/include/c++/4.9/type_traits`, depending on your gcc/g++ version.

Comment: OK, g++ is installed. type_traits is not in the /usr/include/c++/4.2.1 directory, but it is in my usr/local/include/boost_1_57_0/boost directory -- which I added to the include path.